# Automatically clearing tmp files in webgrind

Tags: php, profiling, memcached, wamp, xdebug

I use webgrind, and it produces large amounts of cache files.

How do i automatically clear those files after the server closes or something like that. I use WAMP installation on a windows7 machine.

It may sound silly, But i am not sure how to disable webgrind temporarily on wamp. Also does webgrind add considerable overhead while executing scripts?

**PS**: webgrind is used interchangble with xdebug in the above statements.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, xdebug profiling adds some overhead to execution.

In your php.ini (or xdebug.ini) file, set:

`xdebug.profiler_enable=0`

`xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1`

Now cachegrind files will *only* be generated when you GET/POST with a parameter, or send a cookie, with the name `XDEBUG_PROFILE`.

Example:
`http://yoursite.com/yourscript.php?XDEBUG_PROFILE=1`

Reference:
http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Comment: I had my server break twice with disk full because of these huge tmp files I had enabled inadvertently. Maybe there should be some warning about this in the php.ini file. It doesn't look dangerous. It doesn't blow up immediately, only months later. Ouch.

Comment: after these changes, can you "flush" these files to make them smaller?